# lessc: command not found (terminal)

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, less

I can't use lessc. I have installed npm and node, which are located in usr/local/bin. When I install less via "$ npm install -g less" it is creating a new folder in Users/User/ called "npm-global":

```
/Users/User/npm-global/bin/lessc -> /Users/User/npm-global/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less@2.7.1 /Users/User/npm-global/lib/node_modules/less
├── graceful-fs@4.1.6
├── mime@1.3.4
├── image-size@0.5.0
├── source-map@0.5.6
├── errno@0.1.4 (prr@0.0.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
└── promise@7.1.1 (asap@2.0.4)
```

And then I type lessc and get that "this command is not found". Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: It is OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this folder

```
/Users/User/npm-global/bin
```

is not already in your `PATH`, you can add it in your `~/.profile` file, e.g., by adding a line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/User/npm-global/bin
```

at the end of the file.  Presumably

```
/Users/User/npm-global/bin
```

is meant to be

```
/Users/$USER/npm-global/bin
```

which would allow you to simplify it (since the shell is `bash`, which expands tilde):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm-global/bin
```

Comment: Why use `/Users/$USER` rather than `$HOME`?

Comment: I was writing so that OP could match the string against his/her example, pointing out that the `User` was likely not the actual name.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew that the problem was in the path, but I couldn't adjust it that easy. Thanks!